# How to join a table with null values

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
Tasks
------
Id         int
Name       varchar(100)
StatusId   int (FK)

Status
------
Id           int
Description  varchar(100)
```

The following values exist

```
Tasks
------
Id    Name    StatusId
1     Test1   1
2     Test2   NULL
3     Test3   2

Status
-------
Id     Description
1      Failed
2      Aborted
3      Succeeded
```

Now, I need to show all the values in Tasks with their statuses. The following query doesn't works on NULL values in Tasks Status Id column

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Name, s.Description FROM Tasks t
JOIN Status s on s.Id = t.StatusId
```

What I want the output to be:

```
Tasks
------
Id    Name    Description
1     Test1   Failed
2     Test2   NULL
3     Test3   Aborted
```

Instead I get

```
Tasks
------
Id    Name    Description
1     Test1   Failed
3     Test3   Aborted
```

What is the best way to get all the NULL values also via a JOIN or otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Name, s.Description 
FROM Tasks t
LEFT JOIN Status s 
  on s.Id = t.StatusId;
```

[Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins):

[image]

```
SELECT <select_list>
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B
ON A.Key = B.Key
```

---

You may also use correlated subquery (inefficient):

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Name,
  (SELECT Description FROM Status s WHERE s.id = t.StatusId) AS  Description 
FROM Tasks t
```